# Increment a String by 1 character in for loop (Python 3)

Tags: python, string, increment

Let's say I have an input string str and I want to increase it's value by 1 digit each loop so 'a'->'b' & 'm'->'n', and when it reaches 'z' it increases as shown in the example below.

```
str= "aaaaa"
output= "aaaab"

str="aaaaz"
output="aaaba"

str ="kbzzz"
output="kcaaa"
```

I hope you get the idea, it is sort of like a car's odometer.
How to implement this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach (using a [for-else loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)):

```
def increment(s):
    for i in range(len(s)-1, -1, -1):
        if s[i] != "z":
            break
    else:
        return "a" * (len(s) + 1)
    return s[:i] + chr(ord(s[i]) + 1) + "a" * (len(s) - i - 1)

>>> increment("aaaaa")
'aaaab'
>>> increment("aaaab")
'aaaac'
>>> increment("aazz")
'abaa'
```

1. go through the string from the back
2. stop at the first non-"z"
3. if no non-"z" is found, return all "a" (increase length)
4. otherwise increment the non-"z" and reset the suffix to all "a"s

**Some documentation:**

- [for-else](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)
- [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)
- [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)